# How to set the order of required user actions?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to first have a user enter credit card information and then agree to terms and conditions. Currently, the app is forcing a user to check terms and conditions and then enter credit card information. What is a better method or better way to do this? I am not strong in Objective C.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(_agreedToTerms){

        if(!_canceledScan){
    CardIOPaymentViewController *cardV = [[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc]initWithPaymentDelegate:self];
    [cardV setCollectCVV:NO];
        //CardIOPaymentViewController *cardV = [[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc]initWithPaymentDelegate:self];
     [cardV setCollectExpiry:YES];
       // [cardV setCollectPostalCode:YES];
        [self presentViewController:cardV animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }else{

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please agree to terms" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)
                                {

                                }]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not let the user choose the order in which they do those things? Let them agree to the T&C _and_ enter a credit card, and don't just don't let them proceed until both conditions are satisfied.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you for responding! The person I was building the app for felt it was bad design. Do you know how I could implement entering credit card information first?

Answer (score 0):

> What is a better method or better way to do this?

You haven't shown us enough code to make a specific recommendation, but in general if you want things to happen in a different order, then you need to change the order in which the code makes those things happen. For example, let's say you have a view controller that asks users to accept terms and conditions and another that lets them enter credit card info. The order in which those view controllers are presented to the user is entirely up to you, and swapping them should be a pretty simple matter: you'll either re-arrange them in the storyboard, or you'll swap their positions in the code that presents them.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try.